# Two-way key index with MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, key

I was wondering if it was possible to have a two-way key index in a MongoDB instance. Say, if there was a pair `"foo":"bar"`, I would be able to efficiently access the pair by querying for either `foo` or `bar` (and it would return either the pair or the other key). Is this possible? If not, what is the best way I can go about doing this?

I have tried looking for something like this on the MongoDB documentation for indexes but could not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

If your key is expected to have different values , better you just create different keys assigning your original key/value pair as values as follow:

```
key1:"foo"
key2:"bar"
```

and create index on both key1 and key2 ..

Comment: As in, I would have a pair `"foo":"bar"` and a separate pair `"bar":"foo"`?

Edit: Never mind, didn't read thoroughly. Got it now.